# Trouble with Google Maps, Google Earth turning blue

Tags: google-maps

Why does my map turn blue on Google Maps when I switch to the Earth view

Comment: More information please. What browser are you using, which operating system? Does it happen in any browser or just a single one? Do you have any plugins installed, etc.

Comment: It's the ocean!

Answer (score 2):

Try the sattalite view for a similar view.  The "earth" feature is a seperate plug-in, it uses full 3D and I believe is the web version of GoogleEarth.  I would far rather run the actual GoogleEarth application without the web browser.
   http://www.google.com/earth/index.html

If you cannot load it, and also do not get the flag about the needs, it could be many things,  The plug-in removed even though it is indicated in the registry. some blocker, script block,  security, active-x not being on, it needs java , or some other programming base to operate.

If you have the plug-in and all of that is working correct (even though you dont get view), remember still this is going to be highly GPU based 3D rendering. Checking dxdiag, having all the right gpu drivers would be in addition to the web stuff all working correct. If your using 2 monitors, or are Virtual, it could be a different grafics render issue.

You need to tell what is the OS your using, and what Browser your using, please add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a bug, regardless of how good your ISP is.
You fix it by switching to satellite view and back to map view.

Comment: or its simply the ocean... as said before!

Answer (score 0):

Certain areas of the Google earth map I view have a blue haze over areas and I suspect but am not certain this could be flood zones or zones where recent flooding took place.

Comment: Is this your final answer?

Answer (score 0):

Go to View and deactivate the Atmosphere layer! that did it for me